# Campo de Busqueda usando typeahead

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo un par de `inputs`, uno que busca emails en la BD, con la opción de autocompletar y el otro donde deseo guardar el id del email que encuentre.
La búsqueda con autocompletar va muy bien, pero no se como ubicar en el segundo campo el id que está búsqueda trae. 
Comparto el código:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="@Email" required autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod" id="cod" required>
```

El Script:

```js
$(document).ready(function () 
{
 $("#email").typeahead({
  source: function (query, resultado) {
   $.ajax({
    url: "modelos/usuarios.modelos.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {query: query},
    success: function (data) {
      resultado($.map(data, function (item) 
      {
        return item[0];
      }));
    }
   });
  }
 });
});
```

Y lo que arroja el JSON es lo siguiente:

```
[{0:hola@hotmail.com, 1:8},{1:bye@gmail.com, 1:1},{2:algoporaca@gmail.com, 1:7}]
```

Cómo puedo capturar la id, el cual viene `item[1]`, del email seleccionado?

Comment: Lo que realmente me parece un poco complicado es entender lo que quieres...Si tienes la respuesta del servidor que es lo que contiene `item` y en la posicion 1 de item tienes el email... que es lo que quieres? Insertar ese ID en el input?

Comment: Hola David, si, quiero pasar el id al otro campo, al que se llama cod,gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aca tienes una posibilidad.
No la he probado pero deberia funcionar.
Aca tienes la documentacion
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
 $("#email").typeahead({
  source: function (query, resultado) {
   $.ajax({
    url: "modelos/usuarios.modelos.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {query: query},
    success: function (data) {
      resultado($.map(data, function (item) 
      {
        $("#cod").val(item[1]);
      }));
    }
   });
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Hola David, gracias por responder, aunque está solución la había realizado anteriormente y me arroja siempre es el último id de la BD, no el que selecciono en el campo email.

Comment: Tienes que revisar lo que hay en la variable `ITEM`
Puede que lo que este mal sea lo que pasa en el archivo `PHP` que recibe lo que estas mandando

Comment: Vale, lo revisare, que pena contestar ahora, estaba ocupado en otras actividades, cualquier cosa informo, gracias por todo David.

Comment: Gracias David, esta madrugada le dedique un tiempo y segui la sugerencia que planteo de revisar el archivo PHP, cambie la respuesta JSON y algo del AJAX también fue modificado. Gracias